# link to subpages in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a single page jquery mobile application in which there are few parent pages (directly under body) and few child pages dynamically generated (with backbone.js) and kept within another div.

While linking the pages the parent pages are working fine but the pages inside a simple div are not working.

The following is the simple fiddle to describe the problem. Page-2 is working fine but Page-3 within a Div is not changing.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwhEB/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a extra div wrapped around page 3

- http://jsfiddle.net/zwhEB/1/ (Commented out the extra div, working)

HTML

```
<!-- Remove this extra div -->
<!-- <div id="pages"> -->
    <div data-role="page" id="p3">
        <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back">
               <h1>Header Page 2</h1>
        </div>

        <div  data-role="content">
            <p>This is page2</p>
        </div>

        <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div>
    </div>
<!-- Remove this extra closing div -->
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: but I need that extra div. I am generating bunch of pages in that div dynamically.

Comment: why do you need the extra div? could you add the id attribute to the body tag and use that to append the dynamic HTML pages?

Comment: i am using the backbonejs to generate pages based on templates, if i give body as a wrapper it appends the pages at top and that disturbs the page structure

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zwhEB/5/ I took page 3 and made it append to the body

Comment: i have resolved the issue by changing the backbone view code. although that required me to add attributes to find out parent pages and child pages.